# Is there a way to optimize this code, as this is taking hours to execute

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:99653)
{
  for(j in 1:3226)
    {
    if (grepl(cdata$LegDigitsDialed[i],sdata$SavedPhone[j]) == TRUE)

        {
          cdata$category[i] = "Supplier"
          cdata$su_name[i] = sdata$sushortname[j]
        }

      else
        {
          cdata$category[i] = "Customer"
          cdata$su_name[i] = "Null"      
        }

    }
}
```

I have two data frames and I want to categorize each element of a column based on the presence in the second data frame.

My data looks like this:

```
>cdata
LegDigitsDialed
"a"
"b"
"c"


>sdata
SavedPhone
"aa"
"c"
```

What I want is;

```
LegDigitsDialed     category
"a"                 "Supplier"
"b"                 "Customer"
"c"                 "Supplier"
```

So basically my pseudo code is

```
for (i=1,i<100000,i++)   for(j=1,j<3500,j++)
      {
        if (j contains i) //partial string matching
            populate i(different column) with some value
        else
            populate i(different column) with some other value
      }
```

this script in R has been running for over 24 hours now, and only one third of the records have been processed. Is there anyway to optimize this code.

Comment: Can you please make it a reproducible example, so we can help you? (i.e., it would help if we can just run your code and see the problem)

Comment: U could use the dput() function

Comment: Also: if I get it correctly, your code is probably not doing, what you want it to do. It overrides `cdata$category[i]`for example 3226 times, i.e. only the last value is written. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

As written above, there is probably something wrong with your code, but already answering the 'how-to-speed-up' part of the question:

You can get rid of both `for` loops (and probably be a thousand times faster, if you get the answers to your `if` questions like this.

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b")
vec2 <- c("ab", "a", "b", "c")

sapply(vec1, grepl, x = vec2)
```

This gives

```
         a     b
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for one string-match in a different column and row and additionally save results for this match in the original row index, the following may help:

```
library(dplyr)
# generate example data
cdata <- data.frame(SavedPhone = c("a_a", "a_b", "a_a", "x_y"),
                LegDigitsDialed = c("a", "b", "c", "a"),
                sushortname = c("Max", "Moritz", "Something", "Max"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)

# run one loop within `dplyr`
cdata %>% 
  do({

    # initialize no match values
    category <- rep("Customer", nrow(.))
    su_name <- rep("NULL", nrow(.))

    # loop through `LegDigitsDialed` column
    for(idx in 1:nrow(.)) {

      # find matching index if possible
      search_idx <- which(grepl(.$LegDigitsDialed[idx], .$SavedPhone)==T)

      # overwrite default value
      category[search_idx] <- "Supplier"
      su_name[search_idx] <- .$SavedPhone[search_idx]
    }

    # return data frame
    data.frame(category=category, su_name=su_name, 
               LegDigitsDialed=.$LegDigitsDialed, SavedPhone=.$SavedPhone,
               stringsAsFactors=F)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a replica data frame of sdata to add additional column.

```
new.sdata <- sdata
new.sdata$category <- "Supplier"
```

You can then use `lapply` and `pmatch` function:

```
cdata$category <- lapply(cdata$LegDigitsDialed, function(x) new.sdata$category[pmatch(x, sdata$SavedPhone)])
cdata$su_name <- lapply(cdata$LegDigitsDialed, function(x) sdata$sushortname[pmatch(x, sdata$SavedPhone)])
cdata$category[is.na(cdata$category)] = "Customer"
cdata$su_name[is.na(cdata$su_name)] = "Null"
```

`lapply` is for iteration for all elements, while `pmatch` does partial matching.

Please let me know the result.